# IE Bug: toggleClass and overflow:hidden issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, debugging

Having difficulties with IE (9 and 10). Have not tested IE8, but it's probably the same scenario.

**Brief description:**

- I have a blog post inside a `<div/>`
- I am restricting the `height` of the `<div/>` with a `.height` class set at `100px` and `overflow:hidden`.
- Upon clicking an "Expand" link the `.height` class is removed with jQuery and the `<div/>` expands to its full height, to display the entire blog post.
- Works beautifully in Firefox and Chrome.
- In IE the `<div/>` expands as expected, but all images that were hidden before the expand are still hidden.
- To make those items appear in IE, you have to resize the browser or scroll the `<div/>` out of the viewport and back again.

[Here is a JSFiddle that showcases the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/csq5n/1/)

I am using this code to do the jQuery magic:

```
$('#BLOG').on('click', '.expand', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.POST-WRAPPER').find('.post').toggleClass('height')
                                                .toggleClass('overflow');
});
```

But to fix the problem, I need to (somehow) force IE to 'repaint' the once hidden part of the `<div/>` as it's expanded.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1, very nice bug! And so surprising it concerns the dirty ones from Redmond. Btw.: IE8 seems not to have this bug.

Comment: Hahaha, IE is so funny. [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/EZrkH/) works... until you uncomment the `margin` and `padding` reset on the beginning. ["I LOVE THIS COMPANY!! YEEAAAHHH!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvsboPUjrGc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normally I would not suggest a hack, but since this one is a bug, a hack seems to be ok: Try to force IE the redraw somehow. One solution that works and in your example does not have any visible side effects is using `padding-left` on the `<img/>`:

```css
img {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.height img {
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pYTGK/).

---

Sidenote: You should reconsider the class names. Better use "expanded" or "collapsed" or something else that's meaningful. And you do not need the `overflow` class because `overflow: visible` is the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) anyway. Could be like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYTGK/1/).

Comment: Linus, this is splendid. Just splendid. Exactly what I was looking for. In my case I ended up using `padding-top` instead of `padding-left` but your concept worked perfectly.  Thank you.  By the way. Nice avatar choice. I'm a big Peter Falk / Columbo fan. Cheers!