# toggleClass() is not working in IE11 but seems to work in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Here is my code:

Jquery:

```
$("#welcome-done").on("click", function(){
    $(".welcome-box").toggleClass("hide");
})
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.welcome-box {
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-top: 6px solid;
    border-top-color: #0072FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 170px;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 700px;
    z-index: 700;
}
```

It works in firefox, chrome, safari but for some reason it does not work in IE11... Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

EDIT:

The following code does not seem to work in IE11 either (despite working in all other browsers)

```
$("#welcome-done").on("click", function(){
    $(".welcome-box").toggle();
})
```

EDIT 2:

My console in IE11 is now showing this error (though this error does not appear in any other browsers):

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
File: app.js, Line: 10397, Column: 10
```

Comment: No reason what is shown shouldn't work. Any errors in dev tools console? Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE Bug: toggleClass and overflow:hidden issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802941/ie-bug-toggleclass-and-overflowhidden-issue)

Comment: Per your edit something else is wrong. Are there any errors in dev tools console? Where's the full example?

Comment: I just added the full css. No errors in the console.

Comment: which jquery version you are using?

Comment: @whoami this is the jquery link I am using: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: @cookiekid there must be something else interfearing with your code.I just tested this on IE11 and it works as expected.

Comment: hmmm, my console is now showing an error SCRIPT:1003: Expected ':'

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented this just to show or hide al element you could use the `toggle` method as follows:

```
$("#welcome-done").on("click", function(){
    $(".welcome-box").toggle();
});
```

More about the `toggle` method [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: still does not seem to work on IE11 - works on other browsers though

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in internet explorer and toggleClass which is unfortunate.

There is a hack that will work. For example having in the CSS

```
#welcome-done{
    Padding-left: 0;
}

#welcome-done .hide{
    Display: none;
    Padding-left: 1px;
}
```

Using the padding is to force a redraw which seemed to fix my issue in the past.